# OpenSAML HTTP Post Binding

Tags: opensaml

I'm trying to learn what the correct way is for an Identity Provider to respond with a SAML assertion using OpenSAML. Does anyone have examples of this code?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at : https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php for the format of SAML responses with Signed/encrypted assertions.

Example IDP implementation using OpenSAML is available in the project: https://github.com/OpenConext/Mujina and has the code to generate SAML assertions.

Hope this will help.